# how to save dictionary as excel file

Tags: python, dictionary, xlwt

I am trying to save a dictionary like :

```
Allfiles={'woof': '0', 'jpg': '0', 'js': '45', 'gif': '0', 'css': '11', 'png': '6'}
```

as an Excel file.

And my code is like:

```
workbook=xlwt.Workbook(encoding='ascii')
sheet1=workbook.add_sheet('Parsed data')
for col, caption in enumerate(Allfiles):
    sheet1.write(0,col,caption)
    for row,item in enumerate(Allfiles[caption]):
        sheet1.write(row+1,col,str(item))
workbook.save('savexl.xls')
```

When I check the Excel the output is ridicules. Sorry my reputation is not enough to post a picture, but the problem is that the program treats integer '11' and '45' as string and put them in different cell. But if I didn't set those values to string, an error said "int is not iterable". So any one can help me out?

---

Update:
a new dictionary like:

```
Alllists={'scrip': ['10.183.195.140'], 'host': ['edigitalsurvey.com', 'ichef.bbci.co.uk',        'notify3.dropbox.com', 'sa.bbc.co.uk', 'static.bbci.co.uk', 'www.bbc.co.uk'], 'dstip': ['108.160.162.38', '212.58.244.69', '46.236.9.36', '77.72.112.168', '81.23.53.170', '81.23.53.171'], 'referer':    ['http://static.bbci.co.uk/frameworks/barlesque/2.60.6/orb/4/style/orb-fixed.css', 'http://static.bbci.co.uk/h4discoveryzone/0.233.1/style/h4discoveryzone.css', 'http://static.bbci.co.uk/h4drawers/0.66.1/style/h4drawers.css', 'http://static.bbci.co.uk/h4more/0.114.2/style/h4more.css', 'http://static.bbci.co.uk/h4popular/0.130.1/style/h4popular.css', 'http://static.bbci.co.uk/h4whatson/0.176.5/style/h4whatson.css', 'http://www.bbc.co.uk/'], 'server': []}
```

When I use code:

```
for col,caption in enumerate(Alllists):
    sheet1.write(4,col,caption)
    for row,item in enumerate(Alllists[caption]):
        sheet1.write(row+1,col,item)
workbook.save('savexl.xls')
```

btw, the new dictionary should be saved under the other 2 in the Excel file.

I got a trace back said:

```
sheet1.write(row+1,col,item)
Exception: Attempt to overwrite cell: sheetname=u'Parsed data' rowx=1 colx=0
```

Anyone got idea?

Comment: What output-format do you expect? Keys as rows or columns?

Comment: "But if I didn't set those values to string" yes you did : `'css': '11'`. How did you create your dictionary? When did you have `"int is not iterable"`?

Answer (score 1):

Your dictionary has only one row instead of list of rows. You can change your dictionary structure like that:

```
Allfiles={'woof': [0], 'jpg': [0], 'js': [45], 'gif': [0], 'css': [11], 'png': [6]}
```

or change your loop to something like:

```
workbook=xlwt.Workbook(encoding='ascii')
sheet1=workbook.add_sheet('Parsed data')
for col, caption in enumerate(Allfiles):
    sheet1.write(0,col,caption)
    sheet1.write(1,col,Allfiles[caption])
workbook.save('savexl.xls')
```

to work with original dictionary.

The only reason your code does not throw exception is because string in python counts as a list of characters so you can use '11' as ['1', '1'].

Comment: Hi here is a new problem, can you check updates and have a go?TY!

Comment: Your caption goes to 4th row. One of your items overwrites the caption. xlwt by default throws exception when you write twice into the same cell. Probably you should write caption into 1st row ( `sheet1.write(0,col,caption)` ) or write items into rows below 4 (i.e. `for row,item in enumerate(Alllists[caption], 4)` will start enumerating from 4)